# Realtime updating textfield messages in winforms

Tags: c#

I have a service that add items to a class and then serialize a class into a file.

Then I need to create a simple form C# with a textfield (multiline) showing realtime from the deserialized file.

I will have timer every second that will read my List of a property of the class and show it in a textfield.

My question here is:

> Is there a way that instead of reading again and again the file I can just get the latest rows added and just append to the textfield?

Answer (score 1):

```
var file = File.OpenRead("abc.txt");
file.Seek(1000, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Reading a file, use "Seek" to skip old data.

Answer (score 0):

just a suggestion:

I think, you should rather use some sort of message queue for this purpose.

Again per your post, instead of directly fetching from file, it would be good if you rather store the deserialized content in a `stack`. That way, you can always get the content from top of the stack.

Comment: The problem is that I have 2 separate programs. One write the others read so impossible to share stack between them.

Comment: Message Queue is an option but will have ton install aditional software and its not allowed and the server doesnt have access to internet so cant use any online messaging queue service.

Comment: in that case, you need some global data store. Finally then, this answer makes no sense. But doing a file operation like this won't be efficient to my knowledge.

Comment: Using the file is not an option? why?

Comment: It's an option but will increase complexity. you need to make sure file is not  used already; then somehow know what was the last file line (file pointer to know that) and so that you can read the newly added contents. Sort of issues you face when you perform disk based operation.

Comment: I guess will go with SQLite, small footprint and wont have issues about having access from multiple sources.

Comment: @VAAA, if that has to be the case, then why not go for MongoDB, looks like a document structured DB would be best suite for this rather a relational DB.

Comment: Yes actullay I ended using LiteDB that is a MongoDB Implementation for .NET embeddeed